# Spring Session with JDBC fails at inserting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use a MySql Database to store session information which in theory should be doable by just little additional configuration but I encountered some strange behaviour that I wasn't able to overcome as a Spring-newbie.

What I had was a running Spring REST-API with Spring-Security plugged into it, which was working fine until now.

Looking into some online tutorials I specified information about the datasource in my *application.properties* as follows:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

and put the defined sql-schema script into the specified folder in my resources folder. From what I read this should already be sufficient when using Spring Boot (I am using Boot 2).

As I understood the first entry in the properties file would be equivalent to
setting the @EnableJdbcHttpSession annotation in my application-entry-class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.EnableJdbcHttpSession;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class SpringSecApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[] { SpringSecApp.class, WebAppInitializer.class }, args);
    }
}
```

What I encountered was following behaviour:

1. if I use the @EnableJdbcHttpSession annotation; the required tables are never created.
2. if I leave it out the SPRING_SESSION and SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES tables
   are *always* created independent from the value set for

   spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema

Which I already don't really understand, but if I choose approach 2, which at least ensures table-creation, I will always get error code 500 responses when I try a login caused by failing insert statements into the tables with following trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION(SESSION_ID, CREATION_TIME, LAST_ACCESS_TIME, MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL, PRINCIPAL_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Field 'PRIMARY_ID' doesn't have a default value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'PRIMARY_ID' doesn't have a default value
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:243) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:380) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.save(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:377) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.save(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:129) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:245) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

which can be easily confirmed by inspecting the provided sql-script used to create the tables (I didn't change this default script provided by Spring):

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES BLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

But even if as I understand he values should be set automatically by Spring or am I lacking further necessary configuration?

I don't know if this is important to understand the problem but here are my AppConfig and pom:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    MyRestAuthenticationEntryPoint myRestAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(new MyUserDetailsService());
        auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .and()
                .sessionFixation()
                    .migrateSession();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(myRestAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/secured")
                        .hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/userAsJSON")
                        .authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/unsecured")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(this::handleLogoutSuccess)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    ;
    }

    public void handleLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication){
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(){
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(myAuthenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public MyAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter(){
        MyAuthenticationFilter myAuthenticationFilter = new MyAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        myAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        return myAuthenticationFilter;
    }
}
```

The pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mygroup.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-custom-auth-userdetails-REST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <!--Stresst unter win10-->
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!--Workaround for broken openjdk-version-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I think you need to add `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>` as well, can you add and give a try

Comment: I will try, thank you! Unfortunately I will probably not be able to give immediate response as I am on a different machine today and am fighting some (potential windows-)problems right now...

Comment: Ok, I was able to check after resolving the other issues but it didn't solve the problem; at least I can now get a proper stacktrace from this machine. I will include it into the question.

Comment: I am able to store session details to tables, though using mysql, will share github link

Comment: Check the sample project here: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-session-jpa

Comment: First: thank you for your work! It does work when I manually create the tables and use the code in your repo. I will try to work up from that to find my error source!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the root of my problems, which were in my pom.

My specified spring-boot-starter-parent version was 1.4.x but the table structure for session-information seems to have changed in version 2.x

So with

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

as a parent (and making my own credential-version serializable) it does work now.